# Creating multiple features in Featureclass using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects

I am tried to create 10 points and store in a featureclass.But it store only one point that is p9. How to store multiple points

code:

```
          ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IFeatureLayer flay = lay as ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IFeatureLayer;
            ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeature fea = flay.FeatureClass.CreateFeature();

            ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPoint p1 = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.PointClass();
            p1.PutCoords(0, 0);
            ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPoint p2 = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.PointClass();
            p2.PutCoords(10, 10);
            ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPoint p3 = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.PointClass();
            p3.PutCoords(20, 20);
            ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPoint p4 = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.PointClass();
            p4.PutCoords(30, 30);
            ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPoint p5 = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.PointClass();
            p5.PutCoords(40, 40);
            ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPoint p6 = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.PointClass();
            p6.PutCoords(50, 50);
            ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPoint p7 = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.PointClass();
            p7.PutCoords(60, 60);
            ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPoint p8 = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.PointClass();
            p8.PutCoords(70, 70);
            ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPoint p9 = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.PointClass();
            p9.PutCoords(80, 80);

            fea.Shape = p1;
            fea.Store();
            fea.Shape = p2;
            fea.Store();
            fea.Shape = p3;
            fea.Store();
            fea.Shape = p4;
            fea.Store();
            fea.Shape = p5;
            fea.Store();
            fea.Shape = p6;
            fea.Store();
            fea.Shape = p7;
            fea.Store();
            fea.Shape = p8;
            fea.Store();
            fea.Shape = p9;
            fea.Store();
```

Comment: You're overwritng the shape.. the feature will have the **last** geometry that it was set to. Try making a new feature each time before setting the shape and storing. Is there a reason you're not using an insert cursor and feature buffer?

Comment: I am New to ArcObjects I don't know how to use insert cursor?

Comment: I've added code for inserting using an IFeatureBuffer for illustration.. I won't confuse you with IEditor (yet) but be aware that this code could *still* have problems if, for example, your layers' feature class participates in a topology then you **must** start/stop operation inside an edit session to make any changes. When you've got your head around inserting using a buffer read http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0020000000qs000000 to make your code less prone to common failings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you only have the last point is because you're overwriting (updating) the point with each `.Store()`. You need to create a new feature each for each `.Store()` to create 10 features.

Try this:

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IFeatureLayer flay = lay as ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IFeatureLayer;
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeature fea = flay.FeatureClass.CreateFeature();

ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPoint p1 = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.PointClass();
p1.PutCoords(0, 0);
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPoint p2 = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.PointClass();
p2.PutCoords(10, 10);
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPoint p3 = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.PointClass();
p3.PutCoords(20, 20);
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPoint p4 = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.PointClass();
p4.PutCoords(30, 30);
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPoint p5 = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.PointClass();
p5.PutCoords(40, 40);
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPoint p6 = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.PointClass();
p6.PutCoords(50, 50);
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPoint p7 = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.PointClass();
p7.PutCoords(60, 60);
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPoint p8 = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.PointClass();
p8.PutCoords(70, 70);
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPoint p9 = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.PointClass();
p9.PutCoords(80, 80);

fea.Shape = p1;
fea.Store();
fea = flay.FeatureClass.CreateFeature();
fea.Shape = p2;
fea.Store();
fea = flay.FeatureClass.CreateFeature();
fea.Shape = p3;
fea.Store();
fea = flay.FeatureClass.CreateFeature();
fea.Shape = p4;
fea.Store();
fea = flay.FeatureClass.CreateFeature();
fea.Shape = p5;
fea.Store();
fea = flay.FeatureClass.CreateFeature();
fea.Shape = p6;
fea.Store();
fea = flay.FeatureClass.CreateFeature();
fea.Shape = p7;
fea.Store();
fea = flay.FeatureClass.CreateFeature();
fea.Shape = p8;
fea.Store();
fea = flay.FeatureClass.CreateFeature();
fea.Shape = p9;
fea.Store();
```

The create feature/store feature method is simple but there is a higher potential for failure; if you're adding a lot of features it's best to use an [Insert Cursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0025000002vs000000) (created by [IFeatureClass.Insert](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0025000002t7000000)) and a [Feature Buffer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/CreateFeatureBuffer_Method/0025000002t0000000/), which can be [inserted](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0025000002w0000000) *many* times and creates a new feature for each *insert*:

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IFeatureLayer flay = lay as ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IFeatureLayer;
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureBuffer fea = flay.FeatureClass.CreateFeatureBuffer();
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureCursor FCur = flay.FeatureClass.Insert(true);

ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPoint p1 = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.PointClass();
p1.PutCoords(0, 0);
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPoint p2 = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.PointClass();
p2.PutCoords(10, 10);
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPoint p3 = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.PointClass();
p3.PutCoords(20, 20);
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPoint p4 = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.PointClass();
p4.PutCoords(30, 30);
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPoint p5 = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.PointClass();
p5.PutCoords(40, 40);
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPoint p6 = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.PointClass();
p6.PutCoords(50, 50);
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPoint p7 = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.PointClass();
p7.PutCoords(60, 60);
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPoint p8 = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.PointClass();
p8.PutCoords(70, 70);
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPoint p9 = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.PointClass();
p9.PutCoords(80, 80);

fea.Shape = p1;
FCur.InsertFeature(fea);
fea.Shape = p2;
FCur.InsertFeature(fea);
fea.Shape = p3;
FCur.InsertFeature(fea);
fea.Shape = p4;
FCur.InsertFeature(fea);
fea.Shape = p5;
FCur.InsertFeature(fea);
fea.Shape = p6;
FCur.InsertFeature(fea);
fea.Shape = p7;
FCur.InsertFeature(fea);
fea.Shape = p8;
FCur.InsertFeature(fea);
fea.Shape = p9;
FCur.InsertFeature(fea);
FCur.Flush(); // A flush every now and then clears memory
// release the out cursor and feature buffer to clear memory and release locks
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(FCur);
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(fea);
```

I see that you're using absolute references to objects, you can simplify your code by including `using` statements at the top of your code:

```
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto;
```

Then your code simplifies:

```
IFeatureLayer flay = lay as IFeatureLayer;
IFeatureBuffer fea = flay.FeatureClass.CreateFeatureBuffer();
IFeatureCursor FCur = flay.FeatureClass.Insert(true);

IPoint p1 = new PointClass();
p1.PutCoords(0, 0);
// and so on...
```